# Get Facebook PSID without Messenger Extensions

Tags: facebook, webview, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I'd like to get the PSID of the user, without using Messenger Extensions in a browser.

I'm working on a messenger bot, that lets you buy things. For the payment part, the user is redirected to an online payment site. For whatever reason, the payment web view is opened in a new tab (I guess there's something related to iframes, but that site is out of my reach).

When the payment is done, the user is redirected to `mydomain.com/results.html`. In `results.html` I need to get the PSID of the current user, but messenger extensions gives me this error:

> 2071011 Messenger Extensions are not enabled - could be "messenger_extensions" was not set on a url, the domain was not whitelisted or this is an outdated version of Messenger client.

The described problem only occurs on desktops, everything works fine from phones.

There's already a similar question: [Get the facebook PSID without messenger extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43998604/get-the-facebook-psid-without-messenger-extensions), but using query parameters here is not an option as I can't ask the payment site to include the PSID in the redirect parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Set `messenger_extensions: true` in the URL button and point the URL to a page you control that redirects to the 3rd party payment site. That way you can call `MessengerExtensions.getContext()` or pass the PSID from the chat to your site before the payment flow is initiated.